# Is there any function in Excel that give a number and a range if the number out of a range return the extreme value of the range else the number ？

Tags: excel

I want to know the function build in Excel?

give a number and a range if the  number out of a range return  the extreme value of the range else the number.

example：

```
function A(n,[a,b])):
    if n<a:
      return a
    else if n>b:
      return b
    else:
      return n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should do the trick, where A1 is the value you're looking for, B1 is the lower bound of the range, C1 is the upper bound of the range. You probably don't need the '=' before/after the < or >, it still has the same result.

```
=IF(A1<=B1,B1,IF(A1>=C1,C1,A1))
```

Comment: en,should be this,but,if A1 is a long long arithmetic I should be write three times.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for `VBA` custom function:

```
Public Function CheckRange(ByVal InputVal As Integer, ByVal Rng As Range) As Integer

Dim RangeMax As Integer: RangeMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Rng)

If (InputVal > RangeMax) Then
    CheckRange = InputVal
Else
    CheckRange = RangeMax
End If

End Function
```

Alternatively, using formula:

```
=IF(A2>MAX(B2:B10),A2,MAX(B2:B10))
```

[image]

Comment: thk, the extremal include the  lower bound of the range.

Comment: How do you mean? If this or another answer solved your problem, please don't forget to mark it as complete :-)